# Recognize/raise an alert when a specific service has not been called within a time period by "Developer App"

Tags: apigee

Say I have a resource defined such that the service https://api.mydomainname.com/v1/stores/ABC/order where "ABC" has a direct relation to a Developer App entry.  I also have a Custom Attribute for the maximum number of seconds that can elapse between calls; if the time between calls exceeds that threshold, I'd like to take an action (make an call, raise a Nagios alert, etc).

Example:
ABC (api key: 54c34ce0f7691840093bfba55a10c782) has a 300s elapsed time threshold
XYZ (api key: af9843af2d190f72481183a8645659ac) has a 600s elapsed time threshold

Do we have any ideas on how to do this on for all related message processors in an Organization?

I do not want to have to have a call to check if the threshold has been exceeded.

I'm thinking I have to push this further down to the actual service, but if there is an Apigee based potential solution, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `<LookupCache>` and `<PopulateCache>` policies.  Caching is distributed (across MPs) by default.

You could store the threshold value (300s/600s/etc) as a custom attribute on the develop app.  After `<VerifyAPIKey>` policy, this attribute value should be automatically populated and you can use that reference in the `<PopulateCache>` policy.  Example flow steps:

1. VerifyAPIKey (will get the threshold value for populate.
2. LookupCache
3. If cache hit, continue.  Else, raise custom fault or execute custom logic.
4. PopulateCache to create/update entry, reading expiry from variable reference of attribute populated by #1).  If the entry already exists, it will re-populate the entry with fresh expiration, essentially reseting the last request time.